# Program crashing when jumping from one UITextField to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

```
 if(Field<8)
        {
            [Field1 resignFirstResponder];
            NSString *FieldName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Field%i",Field];
            NSLog(@"%@",FieldName);
            [(UITextField *)FieldName resignFirstResponder];
            Field++;
            FieldName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Field%i",Field];
            [FieldName becomeFirstResponder];
        }
```

I have this code.. [Field1 resignFirstResponder]; works but to do it in the loop i used Field%i method which increments Field name automatically every time.. but the program is crashing on the [(UITextField *)FieldName line.... the Nslog above it is outputting Field1 which is correct.

Any ideas?

I will mark my answer correct in later since so won't allow me now.
**Edits**
I found the answer to my solution here 
Thanks everyone.
   http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/77945-jumping-across-text-fields.html

Comment: Field1 Field2 Field3 Field are all UitextFields i will cycle through.

Comment: Add your answer and select it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a `NSString` to a `UITextField` that is why it is crashing.

Instead to achieve what you want I would suggest creating an NSArray like this:

```
NSArray *myTextFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Field1, Field2, nil];
```

Then iterate over it and do:

```
for (UITextField* myField in myTextFields)
{
    [myField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i t would be really helpful if you can tell how to do this : i want to input password .. so i have 4 textfields for user to fill in and after each character i will make the next one first responder that is what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

[(UITextField *)FieldName resignFirstResponder];

in the above line you are converting string to UITextField.This is incorrect.That's why it is crashing

Comment: i know i am converting an i also it is crashing there.. but this is considered in dynamic typing.. so why is it incorrect.? and any solution you can offer to jump to the next filed by simply choosing Field with incrementation of i like Field1 Field2....

Answer (score 0):

Make an array with your UITextField objects : Field1, Field2 ....
Than it will be easier to handle the next receiver.